# PHP Fibers & Node via PHP Exec

Tags: php, exec, fibers

I'm testing out PHP Fibers and I'm having a problem, probably it's something silly :)
Anyhow I have fibers running a loop and then inside that loop I have PHP exec with sudo nano... that works nice, however it runs 1 by 1, can I anyhow have the loop start node script and just PHP finishes once all are running?

```
self::$fiber = new Fiber(function ($pages, $servers): void {
 foreach ($pages as $pageId => $pageUrl) {
  $siteUrl = parse_url($pageUrl);
    exec('sudo node /var/www/puppeteer.js --url="'.$pageUrl.'" --proxy="'.$proxyIP.'" > /dev/null 2>&1');
 }
}
```

So the code works nice and run, however just instead running 5 exec node at once, it's running 1 by 1...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I didn't have an & on end of the command.

```
self::$fiber = new Fiber(function ($pages, $servers): void {
 foreach ($pages as $pageId => $pageUrl) {
  $siteUrl = parse_url($pageUrl);
    exec('sudo node /var/www/puppeteer.js --url="'.$pageUrl.'" --proxy="'.$proxyIP.'" > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
 }
}
```